# Is it possible to jump to an arbitrary location in a contract's bytecode?

Tags: solidity, remix, evm

The assembly for a smart contract looks like there is a single entry point and a series of if/thens or a switch to jump to the entry point of each function.

Is it possible to skip the lookup and jump straight to the function's code if you already know its offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opcodes that exist to call into a contract (call, delegatecall, staticall) take no parameter to jump to a location in the bytecode. All of these calls will begin execution at the very beginning of the bytecode and there is no way to alter this.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure. Thank you.